# Opera : how to transmit datas to an IFrame via the Frames Array

Tags: javascript, iframe, opera

My main page can send parameters to an IFrame and display it. I use a simple (and cross browsers) method described as 'Frames Array' in [this page](http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/iframes/refs/).

However it works fine in FF, Chrome, IE, and Safari but not in Opera.

The IFrame call :

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.src = 'Layout.error.htm';
iframe.name = 'error';
iframe.id = 'error'; // this is necessary for IE
iframe.style.cssText = "height: 150px; width: 300px";

document.body.appendChild(iframe);

window.frames['error'].data = 'xx';
```

And into the IFrame body :

```
<script>
    alert(data);            
</script>
```

Opera says "Unhandled Error: Undefined variable: data" (IFrame script)...

The data could be sent after the IFrame script has been triggered, so I've tried to add an 'Update' function :

```
window.frames['error'].data = 'xx';
window.frames['error'].Update();
_____
<script>            
    function Update ()
    {
        alert ('data');
    }
</script>
```

But it doesn't 'see' the function : "Unhandled Error: 'window.frames['error'].Update' is not a function" (main page script, even after I've cleared the cache)...

What is the problem of this browser ?

Answer (score 0):

[So](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9717643/2308279) it seems that because of Opera12, the iFrame must be controled from the parent page once it has been completly loaded. This can be done with a callback :

```
<!-- callback into the iframe-->
<script type="text/javascript"> window.top.window.callback(); </script>
```

parent :

```
function callback() {
    var iframe = window.frames['name'];
    var innerDoc = iframe.document;
    // handle the content ..
}
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.src = ...;
iframe.name = 'name';
iframe.id = 'name';
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```